# Community♦-edits change topic title

Tags: support

Something triggered Community♦ to rollback/do some changes on [this question](https://serverfault.com/posts/395277/revisions).

It also changed the title; it added `Undo edits` to the end of the title. It doesn't show up when you have a look at the revisions. I'm sure it wasn't there from the beginning as I had done some research for the Q.

Possible bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit by the community user has already been explained, leaving the question of the "Undo edits".

> I'm sure it wasn't there from the beginning

Your memory is not serving you correctly here; I have looked at the logs, and these (obviously accidental) extra two words where there from the moment the question was submitted (not even in a 5-minute grace period edit).

Answer (score 4):

There wasn't a roll-back, the Community edit was an [Anonymous edit suggestion](https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/7202) (which you actually approved yourself); the title is definitely a bug or something wonky.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I remember there not being `Undo edit`. I assumed some kind of rollback occurred because of the addition to the title.